# How to assign shortcuts to a firemonkey TForm OnKeyDown Event:

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, shift, onkeydown

I'm having trouble assigning a shortcut to a TabItem on Firemonkey, using the form's OnKeyDown event.

It seems that the ctrl key works like it's being pressed and released over and over again.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
procedure TfrmPrincipal.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
   if ssCtrl in Shift then
   begin
      if UpperCase(KeyChar) = 'L' then
       TabItem1.SetFocus;
   end;
end;
```

It doesn't work and after googling a while and found a lot of VCL driven answers, I couldn't find anything that can help me with Firemonkey.

I'm using Tokyo 10.2.2

Any tips?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also you can handle the Key parameter and find your Key value (for ex. Enter key's is 13 or you can just use vkReturn for Enter). As your code says that L key is vkL and its value is 76. So maybe you can just use OnKeyDown event. This will help you; if (Key = vkL) then TabControl1.ActiveTab := TabItem1;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better use an actionlist with an action for that:

```
procedure TTabbedForm.Action1Execute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TabControl1.ActiveTab := TabItem1;
end;

object ActionList1: TActionList
  Left = 176
  Top = 272
  object Action1: TAction
    Text = 'Action1'
    ShortCut = 16460
    OnExecute = Action1Execute
  end
end
```

About your code:

TabItem1.SetFocus is not working, use TabControl1.ActiveTab := TabItem1;

KeyChar in FormKeyDown doesn't have a value when Ctrl key is pressed, use Key for that.